# Are "greatest common factor" and "greatest common divisor" interchangeable?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

Is it reasonable to use the terms Greatest Common Factor and Greatest Common Divisor **interchangeably** ?

Comment: Sure.  Factor and divisor are [synonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synonym).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. These are exactly the same thing.

You could also use *Highest Common Factor* or *Highest Common Divisor*. HCF in particular is taught in various parts of the world (as well as GCD and GCF. I'm not sure about HCD).